# Starting external process in QT without command prompt in Windows

Tags: qt, command-prompt

I'm try to start an external process in Qt with QProcess.startDetached().  I am able to successfully start the process, however when I do this I see an ugly Windows command prompt pop up.  Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use that method as well and do not have that problem. There are applications that create a command prompt when they are started. It may not be the Qt code that's at fault. You can validate that by setting up your code to start a different application and checking if it still creates a command prompt.

```
   QString program = "client.exe";
   QStringList arguments;

   ClientProcess = new QProcess( this );

   // exit calling application on called application start
   connect( ClientProcess, SIGNAL( started() ), this, SLOT( Exit() ) );
   // receive errors
   connect( ClientProcess, SIGNAL( error( QProcess::ProcessError ) ), this, SLOT( error( QProcess::ProcessError ) ) );

   ClientProcess->startDetached( program, arguments );
```

Comment: I tried your process and still saw a command prompt pop up.  Here's my command 
QProcess p;
p.startDetached("ping", QStringList() << "-n" << "5" << "127.0.0.1" << "<" << "NUL" << "2>&1");
What do you think?

Comment: ping requires a command line to operate. If you use notepad.exe instead it should start without a "dos box".

Comment: I think that the process I'm trying to start is making it's own command prompt.  Is there a way to redirect the output?  I've tried using the methods supplied in QProcess, but they weren't successful.

Comment: Sorry, don't know of any way to do that. perhaps this will help: http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2002-10/thread00351-0.html