# opening an exe file in c++ form

Tags: c++, forms, qt

i am implementing an installtion program for my program , i am using c++, QT in debug mode , everything went well till the final stage (run the program after installation)
i tried these two ways for opening the exe file:

```
    QString program= "example.exe";
```

method 1:

```
    QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("file:///"+program,QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

method 2:

```
    QProcess::startDetached(program);
```

but it gives me that error message[image].

Comment: And what happens when you try to run it manually outside of the installer?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778350/starting-external-process-in-qt-without-command-prompt-in-windows

Comment: @RichardCritten it ran normally

Comment: @Valgrind1691 i think i got the starting lead to the problem as my program (example.exe) is a form program with some console output (some indicators i use from that console)

Comment: It just crashed with an unhandled C++ exception.  That happens, it always happens, ensuring that your program runs trouble-free on another machine and fails in a diagnosable way is the other 90% of the project.  Many existing questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible some of application components not founded by executable file. For simple case QProcess::setWorkingDirectory( /* executable directory */ ) can help.
In bad case check environment variables of process in your run. You can loss paths to required libraries.

Comment: thank you , that was the problem . after putting all my resources (images, labels , files and so in the the same folder it worked